# Building a +/- 150V DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, voltage-divider

I'm trying to build a +/- 150V battery powered DC power supply variable power supply.

I have two of these 150V nixie power supplies: http://desmith.net/NMdS/Electronics/NixiePSU.html

And was thinking about putting two of them in series, and setting ground to the middle which gives me -150V and +150V. I would then feed these into two IRF740A MOSFETs (same as those used in the PSU). The IRF740s would then receive an external control voltage to control the output. In my mind the MOSFETs kind of work as a voltage divider. Here is the basic schematic:

[image: citcuit]
<sub>(source: [41j.com](https://41j.com/circuitL.png))</sub>

Does this idea make sense? What have I missed?

Comment: You're going to fry those MOSFETs.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks for you comment? But why? They are rated to 400V (VDS).

Comment: Yes, but they're only rated to 125W.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ah, I only plan to draw maybe 5mA. But in this configuration will they end up dissipating more? I don't fully understand.

Comment: You may end up drawing only 5mA from the output, but in order to do so some current will have to go through the divider. I suggest you be *very* careful about your control voltages.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ah I see. Though the MOSFET to -150V. Hmm what's a better way to do this? Do I need a completely different powersupply?

Comment: I would consider a different PSU. I don't have any suggestion as to which topology to try though.

Comment: I had the same idea but using a pot and a 25v wallwart

Comment: @new299 What is your objective? supplying kid of square wave +/-150V into a load ? and only 5 mA of load current or so? Any other requirements to the 0V center and unbalance of V+ and V- (as the two pow supplies will not deliver 150V sharp)?